# Background animado sobrepõe página

Tags: html, css

Boas,

Estou a fazer uma página de Login, e queria pôr um background animado de ondas para representar a imagem da empresa, mas acontece que ainda não sou muito experiente nesta matéria, e estou a tentar usar um código de outra pessoa no meu para pôr essa tal animação de ondas por trás do Login. Não sei bem porquê, mas o background fica a frente de tudo, e só se ve essa animação! Que é que eu faço?

Ondas (CSS):

```
    @keyframes move_wave {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0) scaleY(1)
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-25%) translateZ(0) scaleY(0.55)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateZ(0) scaleY(1)
    }
}
.waveWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.waveWrapperInner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: -1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #86377b 20%, #27273c 80%);
}
.bgTop {
    z-index: 15;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.bgMiddle {
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.bgBottom {
    z-index: 5;
}
.wave {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.waveTop {
    background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveTop {
  animation: move-wave 3s;
   -webkit-animation: move-wave 3s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
   animation-delay: 1s;
}
.waveMiddle {
    background-size: 50% 120px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveMiddle {
    animation: move_wave 10s linear infinite;
}
.waveBottom {
    background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveBottom {
    animation: move_wave 15s linear infinite;
}
```

Ondas (HTML):

```
    <div class="waveWrapper waveAnimation">
  <div class="waveWrapperInner bgTop">
    <div class="wave waveTop" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-top.png')"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="waveWrapperInner bgMiddle">
    <div class="wave waveMiddle" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-mid.png')"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="waveWrapperInner bgBottom">
    <div class="wave waveBottom" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-bot.png')"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Se puder ajudar agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta colocar `z-index: -1;` na `div waveWrapper` que é onde a animação está dentro.

Acredito que assim, facilita o gerenciamento dos seus `z-index`, alem disso o background vai ficar sempre por último no fundo, e vc não precisa de se preocupar em por `z-index` em outro elementos, além desse -1 da `weveWrapper`

```css
@keyframes move_wave {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0) scaleY(1)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-25%) translateZ(0) scaleY(0.55)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateZ(0) scaleY(1)
  }
}
.waveWrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
.waveWrapperInner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: -1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #86377b 20%, #27273c 80%);
}
.bgTop {
  z-index: 15;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.bgMiddle {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.bgBottom {
  z-index: 5;
}
.wave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.waveTop {
  background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveTop {
  animation: move-wave 3s;
   -webkit-animation: move-wave 3s;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
   animation-delay: 1s;
}
.waveMiddle {
  background-size: 50% 120px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveMiddle {
  animation: move_wave 10s linear infinite;
}
.waveBottom {
  background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.waveAnimation .waveBottom {
  animation: move_wave 15s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="waveWrapper waveAnimation">
   <div class="waveWrapperInner bgTop">
  <div class="wave waveTop" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-top.png')"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="waveWrapperInner bgMiddle">
  <div class="wave waveMiddle" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-mid.png')"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="waveWrapperInner bgBottom">
  <div class="wave waveBottom" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-bot.png')"></div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <p style="color:#fff">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe sapiente ab blanditiis. Non nobis necessitatibus harum eveniet aperiam numquam at magnam quas doloribus nemo maxime consectetur possimus, fugiat earum enim.
 </p>
 <input type="text">
```

Comment: Muito obrigado , era mesmo este o erro que tinha !

Comment: @DiogoPeixoto legal que deu certo tmj